# VideoView stopping on stream

Tags: java, android, xml, android-videoview

my videoview works perfect on mp4 video but for live streaming iptv file .ts it works for about 10 to 15 seconds and then stops so then i have to reopen activity again and again

Here is my code

```
VideoView myVideoView ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_channel2);
    myVideoView = (VideoView) this .findViewById (R.id.channel2);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController ( this );
    myVideoView .setMediaController (mc);
    final String urlStream = "http://192.168.111.55:8181" ;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlStream));

        }
    });

    myVideoView.start();

    myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.setLooping(true);

        }
    });
}

}
```

Xml

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/channel1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```

Comment: please post full xml